# Getting the same site to show with a different domain extension in Google

Tags: google, html, css, internationalization, hreflang

We have one site:

sitea.co.uk

We also own the domain:

sitea.com (redirects to sitea.co.uk)

We want US visitors to see sitea.com both in the browser and in Google when searching for our company name.

However.. We want UK visitors to see sitea.co.uk and want sitea.co.uk to appear when these visitors search via Google.co.uk.

How would we go about setting this up?

Sam

Comment: This will not happen with a redirect.

Comment: In fact, you are not going to be able to do what you want as long as both sites have the same content. As well, it is not wise trying to maintain two sites. It is always far superior to make just one site perform well. The question is this. What is your true goal? What is the heart of the matter?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen several international companies use little flags at the top of the "splash", or front page. US users would click on the US Flag, British users would click on the Union Jack (is that the right name for it?). And the flags would be linked to the respective sites. 
 As a business model, I can only presume that there would be differences between the two sites, just as there are differences between the two countries.